# Dynamically change scale of widgets in Canvas - Python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scale, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a canvas with one useful function for me. I need to make my program understand when object on canvas is too big so this object will collide with borders of canvas and automatically will decrise size of object. I know that canvas can't change size of objects, canvas just change coordinates of object.

So, I did almost everything, and it works, but only first time. If I create a rectangle with bigger sizes again, my program will not change coordinates again. With .bbox function we can see, that coordinates are still the same. I think that after "If statment" I need to update new position of coordinates.

Better just to take my code and try it. For example: maximum size for height is 356mm and for width is 473mm. If you will write into height **357mm** or into width **474mm** -> function "create" will automatically change coordinates with "**.scale**", but only once.

My idea is to write different sizes of the rectangle and I always want to see my rectangle in the middle of the canvas. Not to allow this rectangle touch borders, but if it did -> change coordinates and make it smaller.

How I can make it **each** time when object touching borders?

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

create_win = tk.Tk()
create_win.title("Sample canvas")

create_win.geometry("500x550")

create_win.resizable(False, False)
create_win.configure(background="white")

create_win.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
create_win.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

main_frame = LabelFrame(create_win, text="Sample Canvas", background="white")
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW+SE, padx=10, pady=[0,10])

c = Canvas(main_frame, background="white", cursor="crosshair")
c.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

entry_fields = LabelFrame(create_win, text="Enter data", background="white")
entry_fields.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NW+SE, padx=10, pady=[0,10])

width_lbl = Label(entry_fields, text="Width", font=("Calibri Light", 14), background="white")
width_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

height_lbl = Label(entry_fields, text="Height", font=("Calibri Light", 14), background="white")
height_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

width_entry = Entry(entry_fields, font=("Calibri Light", 14), bd=2, justify=CENTER, width=22)
width_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=[10,0], pady=[5,10])

height_entry = Entry(entry_fields, font=("Calibri Light", 14), bd=2, justify=CENTER, width=22)
height_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=[4,0], pady=[5,10])

create_win.update()
canvas_w = c.winfo_width()
canvas_h = (c.winfo_height() - 60)

#print(canvas_w)
#print(canvas_h)

def create():
    width_entry_int = int(float(width_entry.get()))
    height_entry_int = int(float(height_entry.get()))
    x1 = (canvas_w - width_entry_int) / 2
    y1 = (canvas_h - height_entry_int) / 2
    x2 = x1 + int(float(width_entry.get()))
    y2 = y1 + int(float(height_entry.get()))
    c.delete("all")
    rect = c.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="red", outline="red")
    data = c.bbox(rect)
    print(data)
    if float(data[0]) <= 0 or float(data[1]) <= 0:
        c.scale("all", ((x1+x2) / 2), ((y1+y2) / 2), 0.5, 0.5)
        
apply_btn = Button(create_win, text="Apply", font=("Calibri Light", 14), padx=5, pady=5, bd=0, background="#747d8c", fg="white", cursor="hand2", command=create)
apply_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=[0,10])

create_win.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your codes working.  If you put `print( c.bbox(rect))` after the `if` statements it shows the updated rectangle coordinates.

Comment: Tls Chris is right. if you put print("rescaled") right before scaling, you can see that everytime it works.

Comment: @TlsChris yes, I see that I got new coordinates, but how I can use this new coordinates each time? Maybe I need to use FOR loop somehow? Because now my if statement only works first time, when coords are being changed, if statement is no longer execute.

Comment: @MustafaKÜÇÜKDEMİRCİ what do you think? Please read my answer above, maybe you will have any idea.

Comment: I guess you say that lets assume you enter 9000,9000 rectangle and in current situation it only resize it once and its new coordinates are (-4263, -4322, 4739, 4681) which is touches boundaries. You want to resize it again and again until it not touches boundaries right?

Comment: @MustafaKÜÇÜKDEMİRCİ yes, you are right! Good explanation. Even If I enter 9000, 9000, program should automatically encrease coordinates until rectangle will not touch borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay now, you should change this part

```
data = c.bbox(rect)

if float(data[0]) <= 0 or float(data[1]) <= 0:
    print(data)
    c.scale("all", ((x1+x2) / 2), ((y1+y2) / 2), 0.5, 0.5)
```

into this one:

```
data = c.bbox(rect)
while float(data[0]) <= 0 or float(data[1]) <= 0:
    c.scale("all", ((x1+x2) / 2), ((y1+y2) / 2), 0.5, 0.5)
    data = c.bbox(rect)
```

Now until it doesn't touches walls, it rescales.

Comment: Really-really big thanks, now it works like I wanted to!